# Jaxb to generate the XML directly to the OutputStream

Tags: java

I have a 500Mb csv file. I need to convert it into XML file.
I am using the Jaxb to created the xml file. It is working fine for small amout of data.
but for large amout of data like 300 mb it is throwing out of memory exception.
Can anyone tell me that How can I create each element and write it into a file
 without creating the whole tree using the jaxb?"

Thanks
Sonu

Answer (score 0):

Converting csv to XML you should expect the size of data to be about 10x larger.  I suggest you increase the heap size to 10 Gb if you want to use Jaxb for your whole file at once, possibly higher.

Another approach would be to convert one line of CSV at a time. You can still use Jaxb to do this, but you may find a one line println statement is much simpler.  In this case, you can expect your program will use up to 10x the longest line. (Which might be a few KB)

Comment: Can you please provide any example how can I do one line at a time using jaxb. 
Thanks 
Sonu

Comment: place a header at the start of the file, read one line, generate the XML for that one line, repeat until no more lines, write the footer.

Comment: You can create XML for any sub-node of XML in Jaxb.  The code should be basically the same as what you have already written.

Comment: I would have to use my imagination as to what fields and data types you have and the XML structure you require.  If you are really stuck you will have to post your code so we can suggest how you can change it.

Comment: I am trying to do it line by line it is give @xml root element not found error

Comment: it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation I am getting this error

Comment: Again you would have to show me your code.  Personally I wouldn't use Jaxb here, it just adds complexity.